# Make all elements draggable if they have the same ID

Tags: jquery

Using JQuery, I'm trying to make multiple elements draggable when the elements all have the same ID. Is is possible to do this using JQuery?

(Here, there are two divs with the id "draggable", and I'd like to make both of them draggable.)

The relevant code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/zcJwu/

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery UI Draggable - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
    <style>
    #draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
    </style>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
    <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
    <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>​
```

Comment: `id`s have to be unique.  You would have to use a class instead

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**ID's** in a **HTML** page should be unique..

If you give duplicate **Id's** and use that as a selector, it will always select the first element that it encounters.. `So it will never work.`

Try using a **class** instead.

You can give the class called `draggable` to all the element you want to drag.

```
$( ".draggable" ).draggable();
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/zcJwu/3/)**

Comment: In that case, how can I make all elements of a specific class draggable (using JQuery)?

Comment: Maybe  $( ".draggable" ).draggable();

Comment: So this is part of jquery UI now

Answer (score 5):

You have to use a class. IDs should only be used once.

Comment: In that case, is there a way to make all elements of a specific class draggable?

Comment: It appears that there is: see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13729390/975097

Answer (score 2):

Your markup is invalid because ID's must be unique, however you can bruteforce it into working using this(**Not recommended.**):

```
$("[id=draggable]").draggable()
```

To select all elements that have the draggable Class, do it the same way that you would in a css stylesheet.

```
$(".draggable").draggable();
```

jQuery selectors mimic the css selector style almost exactly. If you know how to select elements with CSS, you know how to select elements with jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

You should use classees, instead of duplicating ID.

```
<style>
.draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
</style>
<script>
$(function() {
    $( ".draggable" ).draggable();
});
</script>
<div id="draggable1" class="ui-widget-content draggable">
    <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>
<div id="draggable2" class="ui-widget-content draggable">
    <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>
```

Check the updated fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/zcJwu/2/

Comment: I noticed that each of these draggable elements don't move to the front when they are clicked - is there any way to fix this (so that they move to the top layer when clicked?)